# Recyclerview Item OnTouchListener

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I managed to set a LongClickListener to an Item of a RecylcerView List. But I want to edit an Item by long pressing and then releasing(following code doesnt work):

```
            holder.mView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() ==  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
                        event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    System.out.println("Action cancel!");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    System.out.println("Action up!");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

this although works but not exactly what i wanted:

```
        holder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("LONG CLICKED");
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you tell us what doesn't work with this approach? Is the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is not called after a long press?

Comment: It doesnt print anything in the run log. The longclick does print me "Long clicked" though. No if Statement returns true in the onTouch listener.

Comment: which widget you are using as your `holder.view`? I've done some tests and `Long Clicked` is called followed by `action cancel`

Comment: Not sure what u mean.  I used the list fragment template from android studio. Its a recylcerview.

Comment: so apparently i needed to set return to true.